# How can I refer to the current block object within my block function?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I know that a block descriptor is passed on the stack to a block function when it is invoked. Is there a variable name I can use to refer to this in my code (like `self` or `_cmd` for methods)

```
(^{
    // how can I access the block descriptor here?
})();
```

**edit**

I actually want the block object, not the block descriptor...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, you can't.   At least not directly (there is nothing akin to `self` within a block -- we thought long and hard about that, but couldn't come up with something both elegant nor enough need for it in light of the following pattern to justify adding such syntax).

If you want to refer to the block, you need to do something like:

```
__block void(^strawberryFields)();
strawberryFields = ^{ strawberryFields(); };
strawberryFields();
```

Note that the above will run forever.  Note also that you might want to copy that block upon assignment if you plan on using the block later.

---

Consider:

```
 NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
 int i;
 for(i = 0; i<5; i++) {
    [array addObject:[^{ return i*i; } copy]];
 }
```

You'll end up with an array with 5 blocks, each capturing a different value of i.

Comment: Amongst other cycles, yes. :)

Comment: Sorry--I didn't realize the block descriptor and the block aren't the same object?

Comment: Ah -- OK -- you just needed the strawberry fields part.  I'm going to delete the other bit about grabbing the innards of the block as that is truly an implementation detail that folks shouldn't generally use (and isn't relevant to this question).

Comment: What I would like to do: I want to associate some data with my block that I can refer to on subsequent evaluations of that block.

Comment: @nielsbot: that's exactly what `__block` variables are for

Comment: each copy of the block should have it's own copy of this variable--I basically want a member variable on my block. reading the documentation for `__block`, I thing the variable declared __block will be shared by all copies of the block?

Answer (score 2):

It may help to create a method to initialize each block for you. Here's a quick test that demonstrates each block has its own variable:

```
-(void (^)(void))intAddingBlock:(NSString *)name {
    __block int intForThisBlock = 0;
    return ^{
        NSLog(@"%@ before: %d", name, intForThisBlock);
        intForThisBlock += 5;
        NSLog(@"%@ after: %d", name, intForThisBlock);
    };
}

-(void)testTheBlock {
    void(^block1)(void) = [self intAddingBlock:@"block 1"];
    void(^block2)(void) = [self intAddingBlock:@"block 2"];

    block1();
    block1();
    block2();
    block1();
    block2();
}
```

Output:

```
block 1 before: 0
block 1 after: 5
block 1 before: 5
block 1 after: 10
block 2 before: 0
block 2 after: 5
block 1 before: 10
block 1 after: 15
block 2 before: 5
block 2 after: 10
```